# Meaning of attribute n_layers_ in sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I have trained a model using `sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier` and I want to know how many layers are in my clssifier. The result shows :

```
>>from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
>>clf = MLPClassifier()  
>>clf = clf.fit(train_matrix,train_label)
>>clf.n_layers_
>>3
```

The document shows attribute n_layers_ means :

> Number of layers

Dose it mean there is a hidden layer or there are three hidden layers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`n_layers_` denotes all the layers in the neural network which include

1. Input layer = 1
2. All hidden layers =  `len(hidden_layer_sizes)`
3. Output layer = 1

So if you initialized the classifier as

```
clf = MLPClassifier()
```

The default `hidden_layer_sizes` param  = `(100,)`, so number of hidden layers = 1.

So total layers  = 1+1+1 = 3 as you are getting.

If instead you initialized it as:

```
clf = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(100,100,))
```

Now the number of hidden layers = 2, so total layers = 4

Comment: MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(15,10))
 can you tell me please what this shows ?like 15,10 ?

Comment: @MubeenKhan I'm sorry, I did not understand your question.

Comment: @MubeenKhan It like your 1.  Input layers(based on number of features, you are feeding in), 2. Output layer, 3. Two hidden layers - two columns - 15 neurons in column 1 & 10 neurons in Column 2.